# sending mail using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am trying to send mails using c# in asp.net page on a free asp server. i have wrote this code

```
public string send_email()
{
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("relay-hosting.secureserver.net", 25);
    string to = "eng.mona.developer@gmail.com";
    client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("eng.mona.developer@gmail.com", "XXXXXXX");

    MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress("mona.elsayed.shalaby@gmail.com", "Mona ");
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
    message.From = fromAddress;
    message.To.Add(to);
    message.Body = "This is Test message";
    message.Subject = "hi";

    client.Send(message); 
    message.Dispose(); 
    return "Email Send";
}
```

and wrote this in web.config

```
<mailSettings>
  <smtp from="eng.mona.developer@gmail.com">
        <network host="relay-hosting.secureserver.net" port="25" userName="eng.mona.developer@gmail.com" password="XXXXX"/>
  </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
```

but i have an error called

> Mailbox name not allowed. The server response was: sorry, relaying denied from your location [XX.XXX.XX.XXX] (#5.7.1)

any help

Comment: `relay-hosting.secureserver.net` cannot send emails from `gmail.com`

Comment: i have tested yahoo mail and the same error appear

Comment: `relay-hosting.secureserver.net` cannot send emails from a domain that it doesn't own.  You need to contact your mail server admin and ask what it's capable of sending from.

Comment: most people search the site here before posting questions that have been asked a million times..

Answer (score 2):

It's a security error from your SMTP server, not your code's fault. Probably because you use your Gmail credentials to access a non-gmail SMTP server.

Comment: which mail can i test with

Comment: I guess this is a Godaddy SMTP server, they should give you the access credentials.

Comment: i didn't get it, could you make it more clear, please

Comment: the host you used in your code "relay-hosting.secureserver.net" is actually not free and it requires that you have a hosted website on GoDaddy server in order to send mail from. But if you want to send emails from your gmail directly then you can use your host as "smtp.gmail.com" and port 587.

Answer (score 0):

Make it so that you can allow anonymous emailing from your server where the page resides then you can set:

```
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
```

and

```
    message.From = "noreply@mydomain.com";
```

and like Max Al Farakh said, use the provided SMTP server which you have rights to.

Answer (score 0):

1) If you use `web.config <mailsettings>` configuration (and this is right!) **you should not set `SmtpClient` programmatically, or configuration will be useless!**

```
 SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();  
 MailMessage message = new MailMessage();  
 message.To.Add(to);  
 message.Body = "This is Test message";  
 message.Subject = "hi";`
```

this is enough, no `server` o `from` in code.

2)  As Max's saying, **this is not a code problem: this is a configuration problem**! **Try a server-port-user-password configuration using your mail client** (outlook, thunderbird or any other) and if this works you just have to copy it in  tag.